# Extract only specific string using windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Using Windows Batch script, I need the output as shown below.  Please help.

Input:

```
APP "Default Web Site/" (applicationPool:DefaultAppPool)  
APP "Default Web Site/App1" (applicationPool:App1)  
APP "Default Web Site/App1/Pages" (applicationPool:App1)  
App "Site1/App2/" (applicationPool:App2)  
App "Site1/App3/VD1" (applicationPool:VD1)
```

Output:

```
Default Web Site  
Site1
```

Comment: what parts of the input are fix, what parts are flexible? How do you know, that you need "Default Web Site" and "Site1"?

Comment: My intention is used to extract the strings which fall after "APP "" and ".  If a slash is found between then it should extract the string until the "/" but not the "/"

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "arg_two=%~2"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=/" %%a in  ("%arg_two%") do echo %%a
endlocal
```

test:

```
outputparser.bat APP "Default Web Site/" (applicationPool:DefaultAppPool)
>Default Web Site
outputparser.bat App "Site1/App3/VD1" (applicationPool:VD1)
>Site1
```

But if you set quotes around the input it will not work.

**EDIT**  with a file to process (content is the same as in the question):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file_to_process=.\input_file.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=(" %%W in ("%file_to_process%") do (
    for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=/^"  %%a in  ('%%~W') do (
         echo %%a
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Hi, the text under input will be the input file used in the for statement of the batch file.  And I want the output file to show the values like I have mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

This works with the sample data.

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=/" %%a in (file.txt) do (
   for /f "tokens=1,*" %%b in ("%%~a") do (
      echo %%~c
   )
))>temp.fil

sort <temp.fil |uniq 
del temp.fil
pause
```

The code below is `uniq.bat`
Place uniq.bat in the same folder as the batch file above or in a directory on the path.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" & goto :EOF & Rem aacini 2013

@end

var line, prevLine = "";
while ( ! WScript.Stdin.AtEndOfStream ) {
   line = WScript.Stdin.ReadLine();
   if ( line != prevLine ) {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(line);
      prevLine = line;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "inputFile=c:\somewhere\file.dat"

    rem Extract the required part of the lines
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"
    > "%tempFile%" (
        for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^/^" %%a in ("file.txt") do (echo(%%a)
    )

    rem Remove the duplicates from the list
    set "previous="
    for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('type "%tempFile%" ^| sort') do (
        if not "%%f"=="!previous!" (
            echo(%%f
            set "previous=%%f"
        )
    )

    rem Cleanup
    del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
    endlocal
```

It uses the quotes and slashes as delimiters to cut the lines on the required points. Then the list is sorted to eliminate duplicates from the output

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "val="
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=/^" %%A in ('sort input.txt') do (
  if "!val!" neq "%%A" echo %%A
  set "val=%%A"
)
```

In the unlikely event that a value may contain `!`, then you would need

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "val="
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=/^" %%A in ('sort input.txt') do (
  set "new=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if "!val!" neq "!new!" echo !new!
  endlocal
  set "val=%%A"
)
```